# Why does creating a new List with capacity 0 still have 1 entry?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Unity and I want to create an empty list but I'm not able to do so. I tried:

```
public List<Room> roomsInScene = new List<Room>(); // default capacity is 0
```

I also tried to enforce the capacity like:

```
public List<Room> roomsInScene = new List<Room>(0);
```

In either case `roomsInScene` has 1 entry which is null. This interferes with the rest of the code.
The only option I could think of is to make an init method that does:

```
roomsInScene.Clear();
```

But I prefer I could just create an empty list. Am I missing something?

EDIT:
I was debugging with Visual Studio and with no code after the line

```
public List<Room> roomsInScene = new List<Room>(0);
```

a breakpoint showed 1 null entry. Culprit: if you're familiar with Unity it can externally overwrite the value of the declared field.
I apologize for the situation and thank you all for your time. I should delete this question but I couldn't without providing an explanation.

Comment: Creating a new list does indeed create an empty list.  How are you observing an entry in that list?  Please provide a complete and minimal example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Does calling `.Any()` on your empty list return true or false? What does the `Count` property look like? How about `FirstOrDefault`. I've never looked at the internals of List, I only look at the documented behavior. What does *the rest of your code* look like that is causing you problems

Comment: Capacity is not an indicator for the length of a List<T>

Comment: Turns out that Unity keeps overwriting the value of `roomsInScene` right after initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something wrong if the following has one entry:

```
public List<Room> roomsInScene = new List<Room>();
```

The Count will be zero because .Net uses zero base count, eg

```
Debug.Print(roomsInScene.Count);
```

Result: 0

If you try to access an item at zero it will fail, likely with an Index Range out of bounds:

```
var a = roomsInScene[0];
```

If this isn't the case restart Visual studio, and/or clean solution, delete bin/obj folders and suo file cause something is corrupted. Instantiating a List will create an empty List, with Count == 0 and no items.

Comment: I've tried it on an online compiler and it worked as you, me and everybody expected, correctly. I updated the question.